# Line thickness not controllable tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

I use code below, I don't understand why the "horizontal lines" are thinner than the others.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,
  vector/.style={thick,black,>=stealth,->},
  atom/.style={blue}
  ]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=none,
    xmin=-0.1,
    xmax=2.1,
    ymin=-0.1,
    ymax=2.1,
    zmin=-0.1,
    zmax=2.1,
   % xtick=\empty,
  %  ytick=\empty,
  %  ztick=\empty
    ]        
    \coordinate (A0) at (axis cs:0,0,0);
    \coordinate (A1) at (axis cs:0.2,0.5,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (axis cs:0.6,0.4,0);
    \coordinate (A3) at (axis cs:0.8,0.9,0);
     \coordinate (A4) at (axis cs:0.2,0,1);
    \coordinate (A5) at (axis cs:0.4,0.5,1);
    \coordinate (A6) at (axis cs:0.8,0.4,1);
    \coordinate (A7) at (axis cs:1,0.9,1);

    \draw[blue] (A0) -- (A1) -- (A5) -- (A4) -- cycle;
    \draw[blue] (A2) -- (A3) -- (A7) -- (A6) -- cycle;
    \draw[blue] (A0) -- (A1) -- (A3) -- (A2) -- cycle;
    \draw[blue] (A4) -- (A5) -- (A7) -- (A6) -- cycle;    
     \draw[vector,red] (A0) -- (A4);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). The red link applies the `vector` style which specifies `thick` for the line thickness. The blue lines don't apply that style so they are _not_ `thick`.

Comment: Thanks very much, my problem was that some blue lines were thick and others were not but your scope function nicely solves it. Have a great weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line in the code

```
vector/.style={thick,black,>=stealth,->},
```

only *defines* the `vector` style which includes the `thick` option. This is just the definition of the `vector` style and this does not apply it anywhere.  The red line is created by

```
\draw[vector,red] (A0) -- (A4);
```

which has the `vector` style and applied and thus the red line is `thick`. The other blue lines are all drawn with `\draw[blue] ...` which does not include a line thickness specification and thus those lines are the default thickness.

If you want the same thickness, you could draw them with

```
\draw[vector,blue] ...
```

Alternatively, you could use a `scope` and apply the `vector` style to that `scope`.

[image]

### Notes:

- I also added `line join=round` to get a better image.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,
  vector/.style={thick,black,>=stealth,->},
  atom/.style={blue}
  ]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=none,
    xmin=-0.1,
    xmax=2.1,
    ymin=-0.1,
    ymax=2.1,
    zmin=-0.1,
    zmax=2.1,
    %xtick=\empty,
    %ytick=\empty,
    %ztick=\empty
    ]        
    \coordinate (A0) at (axis cs:0,0,0);
    \coordinate (A1) at (axis cs:0.2,0.5,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (axis cs:0.6,0.4,0);
    \coordinate (A3) at (axis cs:0.8,0.9,0);
    \coordinate (A4) at (axis cs:0.2,0,1);
    \coordinate (A5) at (axis cs:0.4,0.5,1);
    \coordinate (A6) at (axis cs:0.8,0.4,1);
    \coordinate (A7) at (axis cs:1,0.9,1);

    \begin{scope}[vector, line join=round]
        \draw [blue] (A0) -- (A1) -- (A5) -- (A4) -- cycle;
        \draw [blue] (A2) -- (A3) -- (A7) -- (A6) -- cycle;
        \draw [blue] (A0) -- (A1) -- (A3) -- (A2) -- cycle;
        \draw [blue] (A4) -- (A5) -- (A7) -- (A6) -- cycle;    
        \draw [red]  (A0) -- (A4);
    \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can only find keys "line join" both for line and arrows, and "join" for nodes on a chain from the tikz document. Where can I find the document of usage of `join=round` (I tried, this key-val does work in the example)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "correct" key is `line join` (p.167, pgfmanual or p.188, pgfplots manual).